# Substituting symble without removing the column

Tags: r, knitr, gsub, kable

[image]

The added image is created from the following code:

````
  B <- addmargins(table(data$range, data$symbols))
   B[] <- sprintf('%s (%s)', as.matrix(B), paste0(round(prop.table(as.matrix(B), 1), 2) * 200, '%'))
   knitr::kable(B)%>%
   kable_styling(bootstrap_options= c("striped", "hover"), font_size=16, position="center")
   ```
````

The last column is called SUM, which you can see. I want to remove the `%` sign from the last column.
To achieve this, I tried using `gsub` like so

````
res <- gsub("%","", B[ , ncol(B[])])
knitr::kable(res)%>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options= c("striped", "hover"), font_size=16, position="center")
```
````

It does remove the `%` signs, but it also removes all the other columns, and only shows the last column. How can I make it keep the other columns?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: The result of your `gsub` as above is the column after "%" removed. If you only want to revise that column and keep the result of your data.frame, try instead something like `B[,ncol(B)] <-gsub("%", "", B[,ncol(B)])`?

Comment: Thanks @Ben , this is exactly what I wanted. If you can make it so that I can mark your answer as the solution, I'll do that.

Comment: By the way. If I wanted to remove the entire text that says 100%, instead of just the "%" sign, how would I do that? I tried doing: ´B[ , ncol(B)] <- gsub("(100)%"," ", B[ , ncol(B[])])´. But this makes it look like ´()´

Comment: @States Glad this helped - also, see my edited answer on how you can avoid needing to remove "%" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can avoid the need to remove "%" by just adding percentages to columns that do not include the `Sum` column (referring to `B[,-ncol(B)]` instead of `B` or `B[]` in the `sprintf` statement will add percentages to all columns except the last one).

In addressing the posted question, using made up data based on the example image above:

```
B <- data.frame(
  O = c("14 (54%)", "20 (64%)"),
  A = c("9 (34%)", "5 (16%)"),
  AB = c("0 (0%)", "1 (4%)"),
  B = c("3 (12%)", "5 (16%)"),
  Sum = c("26 (100%)", "31 (100%)")
)
```

You can use the following to just remove "%" (original question):

```
B[,ncol(B)] <- sub("%", "", B[,ncol(B)])
B

         O       A     AB       B      Sum
1 14 (54%) 9 (34%) 0 (0%) 3 (12%) 26 (100)
2 20 (64%) 5 (16%) 1 (4%) 5 (16%) 31 (100)
```

To remove the open parenthesis "(" and everything after it (follow up comment) you can do:

```
B[,ncol(B)] <- sub(" \\(.*", "", B[,ncol(B)])
B

         O       A     AB       B Sum
1 14 (54%) 9 (34%) 0 (0%) 3 (12%)  26
2 20 (64%) 5 (16%) 1 (4%) 5 (16%)  31
```

To remove both the parentheses and all text contained between them, you can do:

```
B[,ncol(B)] <- sub(" \\(.*)", "", B[,ncol(B)])
B
```

Note: If you have multiple parentheses, you can use `gsub` and a different pattern.